# Why can "return" and "break" appear only as the last statement in a block of Lua code?

Tags: lua, return, break

As the Lua manual states: http://www.lua.org/pil/4.4.html

I'm only interested in any technical limitations or constraints, not answers pertaining to taste or coding standards.

It seems like an odd constraint to me, given a hanging `return` can be very easily added with the statement `do return end`.

Comment: Why you do want have code after `return`? I need this only while debug.

Comment: To avoid parsing ambiguity (or lots of lookahead). See [here](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-09/msg00524.html).

Comment: @siffiejoe - thanks, that link helps to explain the design choice. Feel free to make that response an answer.

Comment: Since Lua 5.2, break does not have to be the last statement in a loop block.

Comment: Why would ever want code AFTER your loop ends/function finishes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To [quote](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-09/msg00524.html) one of the Lua authors in an e-mail on the Lua mailing list:

> For the return statement, it's because otherwise it may be ambiguous:
>
> ```
> ...
> return
> f(1,2,3)
> ...
> ```
>
> Is this a return with no values or a tail call to f?
>
> The restriction on the break statement is a leftover from an
>   experimental break-with-labels. "break f(x)" coud be "break f"
>   followed by "(x)".

For Lua 5.2 and up the restriction for `break` has been lifted.